# Apache Ant - directory property from property file for exec dir throws: The directory does not exist

Tags: ant

ant cant interpret well an property from property file what is directory

```
**props.properties**
wdir='C\:/Temp'

**buildfile.xml**
<property file="./props.properties"/>
...
35:<exec dir="${wdir}/bin" executable="cmd.exe">
36: <arg line="/c standalone.bat"/>
37:</exec>
...
OUTPUT

buildfile.xml:35: The directory c:\basedir'C:\Temp'\bin does not exist
```

What did i wrong, how can use wdir property to use it in tasks ?

Thanks in advance
Csaba

Answer (score 0):

ant exec dir doesnt work with absolute paths, dir must be relative.